# Connection pooling in spring WebClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I want to use Spring WebClient in a project to consume some external web service.

1. Can `WebClient` object be singleton or shared among all threads (requests)?
2. If my application is going to get millions of requests per second, then do I need to pool WebClient Objects? If yes, I am unable to find any documentation or examples.
3. Does `mono.block()` internally work similar to `future.get()` or `latch.await()`?

Comment: its common practice to not focus on too much optimisation in the beginning. Start by writing your application, then load test it, and then profile and optimise what needs to be optimised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebClient` is a non-blocking implementation of a REST client built on the Reactive Stack, so I guess the only issue you should focus on is to complete a non-blocking call.

> 1. Can WebClient object be a singleton or shared among all threads (requests)?

A standard way I have seen everywhere is to inject `WebClient` as a bean. I find no reason to do any different.

```
@Autowired
WebClient webClient;
```

> 2. If my application is going to get millions of requests per second, then do I need to pool WebClient Objects?

That's a lot! This should definitely need to be solved with service replication, load-balancers, bulkhead, etc. In terms of the client itself, see the following performance of reactive client using newer versions of Spring: [WebFlux Reactive Programming Performance Test](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-20-webflux-reactive-performance-test). Moreover, that is the *expected* maximal throughput?

> 3. Does mono.block() internally work similar to future.get() or latch.await()?

Yes, it does.